# How to show full list of parameters bound to the query on SQLAlchemy error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, loguru

right now I'm receiving an exception, while doing a `bulk_save_objects`, like the following one:

```
(sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: foo.id [SQL: INSERT INTO foo (id, name, created_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?)] [parameters: ((1, 'A', 1111), ecc.. ... displaying 10 of 14 total bound parameter sets ... (2, 'B', 2222))] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

But I'd like to view the **full list of parameters bound to the query**, not only a subset of them.

Do you know how I can do it? Is there any particular setting?

I'm using `loguru` to print the exception `logger.exception(e)`, and I've configured SQLAlchemy this way (for DEBUG purpose):

```
Engine = create_engine(database_uri, echo=True, echo_pool=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=Engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False)
```

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this.  The code is [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/07cd49daaadd0a0568444eaeccaa79f79cd15ffc/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py#L530).  The value of `batches` conditions the display, and it seems to be hardcoded to 10 wherever it's set.

Comment: I thought so too... thank you very much!